# window.opener becomes null in Internet Explorer after security zone change

Tags: internet-explorer, window.opener, security-zone

My application runs in Local Intranet zone which launches a popup. This popup opens another page in my application (Local Intranet zone) which redirects to an authentication page (Internet zone) which after successful authentication sends back to my application page ( Local Intranet zone). However, at the final page, window.opener becomes null and I can't call methods on parent page.

This doesn't happen when all pages load from the same zone. Is there a way around this behavior so that I can call methods on parent page after redirect?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds very much like an intentional security measure - I can't think of a way to circumvent it.

You could try using a [modal dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (see [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1123330.aspx/1?using%20window%20opener%20with%20showmodaldialog) how to address the opener from there) and see whether it behaves any different, but I wouldn't hold my breath - it's likely the same security model applies there as well.